# How does xml comments work between projects in one solution

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, comments, xml-comments

I'm setting up xml comments through properties in project in solution. I want this comments to be seen in other project in same solution. However project and xml being refereenced in bin near .exe isn't enough.

I tried adding the hard link to other project bin folder but it didn't quite work.

I have project tree like:

Solution:

|---ProjectA (referrence to project B)

|---ProjectB (having some summary comments in it generated on build)

I'm using methods from B working as utility methods in project A, but I can't see the summary out of xml. When I'm calling method like
`_something.doAFlip()`
there is no description while calling class and method while it is provided alongside .dll in bin/netframework etc. with name: myassembly.dll and myassembly.xml together.

Comment: Are you using visual studio, what version? You don't need to add references to bin folder files at all (and definetly not to the xml doc).  Just add a ProjectReference to the other project in the solution and ensure your project has `<GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>` (if csproj 2017 format).

Comment: Project A has a refference to B like this:

 ```<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\xx\ProjectA.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>```

And Project B has this generatedocumentationfile which is creating documentation, but although it is generated properly (as I think and can see) it is not shown in intellisense in ProjectA while using methods out of Project B.

VS version: 15.8.2

Comment: I can see in bin of Project a that there is ProjectB.dll and ProjectB.xml copied but I can't see Intellisense in methods anyway. Any ideas why?

Comment: Shouldn't be any reason it isn't showing.  Is it showing correctly within Project B? if you hover over methods do you see the xmldoc?

Comment: yes it is showing correctly on ProjectB

Comment: @ThomasN I posted answer below if you are curious. Made a silly mistake :P

Comment: Ah easily done, did seem strange, xmldoc does usually just work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up, the problem weren't located in XML comments. While you have one solution and more projects inside the VS **should automatically load all comments from summaries without generated doc**.

The problem was itself in class, method and interface and lack of ReSharper. While I was injecting dependencies in ProjectA from ProjectB I was injecting interfaces and not methods. My project had no comments on interfaces and only method and classes were commented. After adding comment to interfaces and functions inside interface I'm able now to see them correctly after injecting in ProjectA :)